# "Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad" error after app closes

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have just been finialising my latest app and have noticed that i am getting this error every 60 seconds in my logcat when the app is closed or the screen is off.

"Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad. Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now."

The ads display fine when using the app, its just this error is bugging me. i cannot work out why this is happening. None of my other apps have had this problem.

It is not causing any problems that i can see i just don't want this app always trying to display ads in the background when closed.

I have included all relevent onResume() and onPause() methods.

Any ideas?

```
public class More extends Activity {

Button share, rate, more;
TextView text;
AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.more);

    share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bShare);
    rate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRateApp);
    more = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bMoreApps);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);


    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adViewMore);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}   

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.resume();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.pause();
    }
super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }
super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide the code causing this warning

Comment: Added. I don't think it'll tell you much though

Answer (score 0):

This is what the doc tells me :

`The View to display banner ads. The ad size and ad unit ID must be set prior to calling loadAd(AdRequest).`

I guess you are setting the size in the layout file but the AdView needs these attributes which are clearly the normal view size properties ( thus not to be hardcoded in layout file ) and rendering the Warning :

"**Ad is not visible.** Not refreshing ad. Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now."

understandable.